# Approximate a non-unit in a local ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be an integral local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Then let $g \in\mathfrak{m}$, $g \neq 0$ be arbitrary.

My question is:

> Is there a power $n$ such that for any $a \in \mathfrak{m}^n$ we have $a/g \in \mathfrak{m}$?

**Edit 1:** Assume $R $ to be the local ring of a proper integral curve, thus we have some relation between $X,Y $ which should give some new room for the statement probably being correct.

**Edit 2:** For intuition, consider the local ring of a singular point, for example take the point given by the ideal $\left<x,y\right>$ in the coordinate ring $k [x,y] := k[X,Y]/\left<X^3-Y^2\right>$. Thus $R = k [x,y]_{\left<x,y\right>}$ and $\mathfrak{m} = \left<x,y\right>R $. Now if we replace $x $ as a generator by $x+y $, we see that $x+y \mid a $ for each $a \in \mathfrak{m}^2 = \left<(x+y)^2, (x+y)y, y^2\right> $ since $x+y $ divides each generator. Here $x+y \mid y^2=x^3$ since $$\frac{x^3}{x+y} = \frac{x^3(x-y)}{(x+y)(x-y)} =\frac{x^3(x-y)}{x^2-x^3}  = \frac{x(x-y)}{1-x}$$ and $1-x $ is a unit.

Comment: Maybe you want $R$ to be a DVR or something?

Comment: @Hoot: No, $R $ should be the local ring of a point on a proper integral curve over a field $k $, in particular the point could be singular.

Comment: The property holds trivially for any Noetherian local integral domain of dimension one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.

*Counter-example*

Let $K$ be a field, $R=K[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}$ the localisation of the polynomial ring in two indeterminates at the maximal ideal generated by $X$ and $Y$. In this ring, $\mathfrak m^n=(X^n,X^{n-1}Y,\dots,X^iY^{n-i},\dots,Y^n)$. If the assertion were true, it would mean that $X^n$, say, is divisible by $g=X+Y$. However, as $K[X,Y]$ is a U.F.D., the decomposition into irreducible factors is unique.

Comment: But the question is if there is $n \geq 3$ with $X+Y \mid a $ for all $a \in \mathfrak{m}^n$. For this you will have to reason why $X^2$ is still in $\mathfrak{m}^n$. This won't be true, but $X^n $ will be, thus your example provides indeed a counterexample.

Comment: You didn't specify $n\ge 3$. Anyway, replace $X^2$ with $X^3$, it's the same argument of factoriality.

Comment: To give a counterexample you have to argue why there is no $n$ such that $g $ divides all elements of $\mathfrak{m}^n$.

Comment: Replace $X^3$ with $X^n$: $X+Y$ is *never* one of its irreducible factors.

Comment: That's what I've answered to your first comment. But what about the new assumption?

Comment: @BrunoBats: I'll have to think about. What do you call an integral curve, or an integral ring? A domain?

Comment: @Bernard An integral curve is a a scheme of dimension one which is irreducible and reduced. One consequence should be that the local ring at any point is an integral ring (a domain).